# How to use the cmd "gnome-software --install=ID"?

Tags: command-line, software-center, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-software

I am trying to use the command "gnome-software --install=ID" to install a gnome shell extension called "blyr". However, I don't seem to be able to get the cmd to do what I want. How do I use this cmd to install a shell extension via cmd line?

The shell extension can be found in `gnome-software --> Add-ons --> Shell Extensions`. Or, the cmd `$ gnome-software --search blyr` will cause the extension to appear in "gnome-software".

Below are the error msgs that i am getting.

```
$ gnome-software --install=blyr   #Nothing happens
$
$ sudo gnome-software --install=blyr
04:40:46:0158 Gs enabled plugins: systemd-updates, packagekit-offline, fwupd, packagekit, packagekit-refine-repos, os-release, desktop-categories, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-local, packagekit-refresh, appstream, desktop-menu-path, hardcoded-blacklist, generic-updates, packagekit-refine, steam, rewrite-resource, odrs, hardcoded-featured, modalias, hardcoded-popular, packagekit-history, provenance, icons, provenance-license, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
04:40:46:0158 Gs disabled plugins: ubuntuone, dummy, dpkg, repos, shell-extensions, epiphany, snap
04:40:46:0856 Gs Need to use a valid unique-id: blyr
#Thereafter, nothing happens and I have to press Ctrl C to escape.

$ sudo gnome-software --install=blyr@yozoon.dev.gmail.com
04:48:55:0162 Gs enabled plugins: systemd-updates, packagekit-offline, fwupd, packagekit, packagekit-refine-repos, os-release, desktop-categories, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-local, packagekit-refresh, appstream, desktop-menu-path, hardcoded-blacklist, generic-updates, packagekit-refine, steam, rewrite-resource, odrs, hardcoded-featured, modalias, hardcoded-popular, packagekit-history, provenance, icons, provenance-license, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
04:48:55:0162 Gs disabled plugins: ubuntuone, dummy, dpkg, repos, shell-extensions, epiphany, snap
04:48:55:0786 Gs Need to use a valid unique-id: blyr@yozoon.dev.gmail.com
#Thereafter, nothing happens and I have to press Ctrl C to escape.
```

I obtained the shell-extension uuid from [here](https://github.com/yozoon/gnome-shell-extension-blyr/blob/master/blyr%40yozoon.dev.gmail.com/metadata.json)

```
$ gnome-software --help
Usage:
  gnome-software [OPTION…]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                    Show help options
  --help-all                    Show all help options
  --help-gapplication           Show GApplication options
  --help-gtk                    Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  --mode=MODE                   Start up mode: either ‘updates’, ‘updated’, ‘installed’ or ‘overview’
  --search=SEARCH               Search for applications
  --details=ID                  Show application details (using application ID)
  --details-pkg=PKGNAME         Show application details (using package name)
  --install=ID                  Install the application (using application ID)
  --local-filename=FILENAME     Open a local package file
  --interaction                 The kind of interaction expected for this action: either ‘none’, ‘notify’, or ‘full’
  --verbose                     Show verbose debugging information
  --profile                     Show profiling information for the service
  --quit                        Quit the running instance
  --prefer-local                Prefer local file sources to AppStream
  --version                     Show version number
  --display=DISPLAY             X display to use
```

Following `--help`, `gnome-software --details=ID` is the syntax. I tried:

```
$ gnome-software --details=blyr                       # This works.
$ gnome-software --details=blyr@yozoon.dev.gmail.com  # Did not works.
```

This result shows me the `ID` should have the value of `blyr`. Hence, I don't understand the error `Need to use a valid unique-id: blyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the author of [blyr](https://github.com/yozoon/gnome-shell-extension-blyr) recommends. Quote:

```
git clone git@github.com:yozoon/gnome-shell-extension-blyr.git
cd gnome-shell-extension-blyr/
make local-install
```

Then just restart the Shell and enable the extension.

To remove the extension just run:

```
make local-uninstall
```

Note:

Some Ubuntu users reported that the preferences dialog didn't appear after opening it from the GNOME Tweaks application. To fix the issue install the gtkclutter bindings as follows

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Blyr is just a test case. Not all shell extension may have a git repository to use this procedure. The cmd `gnome-software --install=ID`  seems like a command that could be used uniformly to install all shell extensions. I am interested to get it working. Any chance you know how to use that command to install shell extensions? I have clarified my question.